# Most practical way to make multiple AJAX requests

Tags: jquery

sort of a jQuery noobie here.. I am wondering if there is a way to merge multiple AJAX requests into one JSON object? For example. If I have...

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "test1.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

**and**

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "test2.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

Is there I can merge the two so I only have one JSON object. And if so would this be beneficial in anyway? Or is there a more practical way to handle multiple AJAX requests?

Comment: You have to merge the result on the server side and return one single JSON

Comment: I assume this would be with PHP or something? There is no possible way to merge it with jQuery?

Comment: I'm note sure about performance, but if you want just one ajax call, you can submit all the parameters to `test.php`, which will include both `test1.html` and `test2.html`, and will create an array: `return json_encode($data);`

Comment: What if you are getting JSON objects using an API? Would you send them to a server and then re-request them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the ajax functions need changed to return a Deferred object which manages the callbacks for a call after all complete. The `done()` function is chained off of `$.when` to declare the code to run when all your ajax calls have completed successfully.

The `done()` function receives an argument for each of the ajax calls. Each argument holds an array of the arguments that would be passed to that ajax call’s success callback. So if you consult the documentation you see the [power of Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

This will add the punch you need in your code.
Hope this helps.
paul

Comment: The link is pretty useful. I didn't know about deferred objects. However I am still a bit confused by it. Would it be possible to get a small code sample? Thanks

Comment: The jQuery.Deferred() constructor " provides flexible ways to provide multiple callbacks, and these callbacks can be invoked regardless of whether the original callback dispatch has already occurred. It also creates a new deferred object. "So we would need to plan ahead and use  deferred.then(), deferred.done(), and deferred.fail() methods when coding depending on the expected result. I know it sounds challenging but believe it is an amazingly beautiful answer to these issues. I now find myself using this  constantly in all sorts of projects. Stick to the basics, this code will come quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick. You have to be careful while using it so that you don't mess things up.
I am giving you an overall logic you can do the complete implementation.

```
function fireAjax(functions_list)
{
 // The variable functions_list will contain the list of functions like "getUsers,getStatsData,getTopnews"

  $.ajax({
    //bla bla bla
    data:{"getUsers[group_id]":group_id,"getUsers[foo]":bar,"getStatsData[limit]":limit},
    success:function(json_result)
            {
              // You have to form the result also according to the function names like
              /* { getUsers:[user1,user2,user3....],
                   getStatsData[stats1,stats2.....],
                   bla bla bla...
                  } */
                  // handle your responses here one by one
            }
   })

}
```