# $.ajax in $.on('click') ran during page load

Tags: jquery, events

Recently, when I have some new function that requires firing $.ajax inside a click event, and I had some code like the followings,

```
$('.ClickMe').on('click', function() {

   // Do something

   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'Foo.aspx/BarWebMethod',
     data: '{}',
     contentType: 'application/jspn',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
       // Do good thing
     },
     error: function() {
       // Do something bad
     }

});
```

I realized that the page would fire the AJAX call to my WebMethod during page load and cached all the result, instead of firing it during someone clicked elements with 'ClickMe' in its class.

Function-wise it is all good, but since I have about hundreds of elements would hook up with the above code, and I certainly don't want to run those hundreds of excessive AJAX calls.  I want to run that piece of code only when users clicked on any of the elements.

Any idea?

Comment: why do you think this will fire without requiring a click?

Comment: `"I realized that the page would fire the AJAX call to my WedMethod during page load"` . Are you sure ?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11534472/946170 this may help

Comment: @Jashwant and Alnitak are right. There's no reason why this should fire at onload. What makes you sure that it is being fired? Have you checked in Firebug, for instance, using the 'Net' tab?

Comment: @Jashwant I am very sure, because I put break point in my ASPX web method, and it runs during page load

Comment: Check 'Net' tab or remove this function and check if your aspx if that runs again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you aren't actually firing the click event somehow.

For simplicitiy I would use the [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) rather than the [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#target").click(function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
  });
});
```

Wrapping the event within the `$(document).ready` will also ensure that the document is loaded before binding the click event.

Also using either Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools (F12 is the default key binding) have a look at what network requests are actually firing when you reload the page.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools - Network]

Using these tools you should be able to get more of an understanding of what your web page is actually doing.

Comment: `on` is the preferred method these days, although I agree with the advice to check what might be making it fire.

Comment: I will agree that I also prefer using `on` but for a simpler approach I think the `click` is easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, it is more self-evident what's happening if you use `click`.

Comment: I have tried to put this code inside $(document).ready() or on its own within a <script> block, I had the same result

Comment: @RonaldTao What results do you get from the network tools? Is the web page actually firing these events on page load?

Answer (score 0):

This won't fire unless something of class clickme is clicked, the conventional way is to attach to document ready.

And if you don't want cacheing turn it off, shown below is the shorthand for document ready

```
$(function() {

  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  ...
  your click handler attached to element
});
```

Comment: Adding the `cache: false;` will only add a parameter to the request. He said he noticed it caching on his server. This would just result in multiple requests with timestamps.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it WILL fire if you DON'T attach it to document ready? It would if there was no `on` closure around the `$.ajax` call, but as it stands it shouldn't call, right?

Comment: He said he was seeing the request on the server not that he wanted to prevent caching. That and it would be better managing the caching on the server not with random parameters.

Comment: @Marrowmaw, I took it as implied that if one cache was bad, so others would be to.

Answer (score 0):

Place your script inside this function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Here goes your script.
});
```